# Type mismatch on Adding Icon to Userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I've been using the same code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38748940/8343981) and finding the same code whenever I search the internet for this, but I'm always getting a

> type mismatch

in `FindWindow` function in the `Sub AddIcon`. Also tried [this](http://cellmasters.net/cd_063.htm), downloaded the sample and got the same error. Any Idea why? I'm using 64-bit version. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 64bit version `FindWindow` returns a `LongPtr` instead of `Long` (32 bit).

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal lpWindowName As String _
) As LongPtr '<-- FindWindow returns a LongPtr (for 64bit)
```

Therefore

```
hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, Me.Caption)
```

fails because `hWnd` was declared as `Long` in `AddIcon()` but should be `LongPtr`.

You can use

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Dim hWnd As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim hWnd As Long
#End If
```

To ensure it works for both 32 and 64 bit versions according to the declarations of the WinAPI functions.

*Note: You might check if other variables declared as `Long` also need to be changed to `LongPtr`. Therefore just look at the 64bit declarations and what the functions return.*

Comment: A very well explanation Sir, Thank you. :) it solved the problem and I understand a bit. :)